# "Semantical Error" line 0, col 14 near 'User u WHERE': Error: Class 'User' is not defined

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 5 project which has default authentication and `User` entity. I was reading [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#the-querybuilder) in order to use `$em->createQueryBuilder()` function but I got this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near 'User u WHERE': Error: Class 'User' is not defined.

I just need to query some users with an specific role so I wrote the following code in the controller:

```php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$category_users = $qb->select(array('u'))
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->where('u.category = ' . $category->getId())
    ->setParameter('roles', '%"ROLE_CUSTOM"%')
    ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

I know the error does not have to do with writing the query itself and I guess this could have two questions, but just in case...

Question 1: What am I forgetting to get this error? I have read in previous versions of Symfony I should add Bundle name to `from('User', 'u')` but I am not sure about this version.

Question 2: Is this code optimal for this kind of query? Or maybe I am overcomplicating stuff?

Comment: `->orderBy('ASC')` looks weird. There should be a field there, right?

Comment: Edited, my fault. But I guess that wasn't the problem.

Comment: I'll guess you need the FqCN - probably something like `Acme\Namespace\Entity\UserEntity` or `UserEntity::class`

Comment: @craigh, yes, Indeed changing `from('User', 'u')` to `from('App\Entity\User', 'u')` started to "work". I still get an error while fetching user roles, but that is another issue... You can post a reply I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a FqCN for the Entity.

e.g. `from('App\Entity\User', 'u')`